# disable bouncing effect of ios in ionic 3

Tags: ios, ionic2, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I have added scrollAssist and autoFocusAssist property in app.module.ts. However it works only for android not for iOS.
how to disable bouncing effect of ios in ionic 3?

```
 IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{scrollAssist: false, autoFocusAssist: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this workaround:

```
.ios {
  <your-screen> {
    .scroll-content {
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;
    }
  }
}
```

However, This is not recommended because it will disable smooth scroll as well. Read more about it here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11584

Answer (score 0):

Try this: in config.xml under platform put

```
 <platform name="ios">
   [....]
   <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
 </platform>
```